# How do you send a Journal to another IBM I?

Tags: websphere, ibm-midrange, journal, journaling

Is there a way to send Journals to another IBM I by just sending the Journal / Receiver ?
Or do i need to also send the table ?

What is the correct way to send Journals / journaled tables ?

When i SAVOBJ a Journal and RSTOBJ that Journal at another machine.
There is no Data in that Journal.

I also tried to journal a whole library and then restored the library on my second IBM I.
There was some Data in the Journal then. But not exactly the same.
When i tried to display that data it showed me there was no data in my table.
The same command worked on my original ibm i though.

DSPJRN JRN(LIB_Name/JRN_Name) OBJ((LIB_Name/Table_Name *FILE)) ENTTYP(*RCD)
OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/Temp_table) OUTMBR(*FIRST *ADD)

Comment: journal entries are in a `*JRNRCV` object, not a `*JRN` object.  I don't think you can move them between systems without remote journaling involved.  But this doesn't seem appropriate for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As Charles pointed out, this is not a programming question but system administration.

The correct way to send journals to another machine is [remote journaling](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=management-remote-journal-concepts).